# NetBeans 8.2 could not install some modules- MAC

Tags: php, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 8 DEVELOPMENT VERSION 2, All packages.

First I used NetBeans 8.1, All packages. Then I was notified that I have updates. So I updated it to 8.2 DEVELOPMENT VERSION.

Then again I was notified that I have updates, and I started updating. But by mistake,

**Now my problem is that when I start NetBeans, I get the following error message :**

> Warning - could not install some modules: Controls.js Support - The module named com.controlsjs.controls4j was needed and not found. ODCS API - The module named com.tasktop.c2c.server.cloud.api was needed and not found. ODCS API - The module named com.tasktop.c2c.server.common.api was needed and not found

So I need help on how to repair my installed copy of NetBeans.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently on a Mac. Reinstalling Netbeans 8.2 appeared to have addressed this problem for me.